# How can I (and should I) make another method call wait until a series of network requests have been completed?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a basic Android app that uses Retrofit to call the Flickr api and get some images. The basic logic is I want to get a list of 100 images with the tag "boat" then pick 8 of them at random and get their URLs so that I can download and display the images on a grid. The Flikr API is set up such that I need to make 1 api call to get a JSON object containing 100 images and their IDs, then use those IDs one-by-one in another api method in order to get each one's URL.

Only once all 8 URLs have been loaded into my array do I want to load the images on the screen. That I why in my `enqueue()` method for the network call that gets URLs I am inspecting the URL array to see if it contains any nulls. Once it no longer contains nulls I know all URLs have been dowloaded and I can proceed with loading the images on screen.

This is for a game of memory and I kind of need to have all the image URLs first so that I can arrange them around the screen properly for memory. At least, that's how I've architected it.

Anyways, the way I'm doing it now (calling a network call 8 times from another network call, and checking for nulls in the array to know when it's done) doesn't feel great to me so I'm wondering if there might be a better way to do it. I've posted my network calls below. You can find my whole MainActivity [here](https://gist.github.com/int-a/6ca976dd2ca7efcf90fc57c5deae6dbc) in case it helps. Any suggestions are appreciated!

These are my network calls:

```
private void refreshImages() {
        Retrofit retrofit = Api.getRestAdapter();
        FlickrServiceInterface flickrService = retrofit.create(FlickrServiceInterface.class);
        Call<PhotosList> call = flickrService.getPhotos("boat");

        // reset Image ID and URL array
        imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotosList>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PhotosList> call, Response<PhotosList> response) {
                photosList = response.body();
                List<Photo> photos = photosList.getPhotos().getPhoto();
                for(Photo photo : photos) {
                    imageIds.add(photo.getId());
                }

                // randomize images
                Collections.shuffle(imageIds);
                // take first 8 images
                imageIds = imageIds.subList(0,(numElements/2));

                buttonImgs = new String[imageIds.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < imageIds.size(); i++) {
                    getImageUrl(imageIds.get(i), i);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PhotosList> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

private void getImageUrl(String imageId, final int index) {
        Retrofit retrofit = Api.getRestAdapter();
        FlickrServiceInterface flickrService = retrofit.create(FlickrServiceInterface.class);
        Call<PhotoSizes> call = flickrService.getPhotoSizes(imageId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotoSizes>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PhotoSizes> call, Response<PhotoSizes> response) {
                PhotoSizes photosSizes = response.body();
                List<Size> sizes = photosSizes.getSizes().getSize();

                // iterate through sizes looking for large square and get url
                for(Size size : sizes) {
                    if (size.getLabel().equals("Large Square")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Adding " + index + " image URL:" + size.getSource());
                        buttonImgs[index] = size.getSource();
                    }
                }

                // If all urls have finished loading buttonImgs array will contain no nulls
                // then we can load images on the screen
                if(!Arrays.asList(buttonImgs).contains(null)) {
                    loadButtonsOnScreen();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PhotoSizes> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using events? Notify the subscribers to trigger the next method call?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good solution huh. I'm trying to not use any libraries other than retrofit though.

Comment: Then write your own Event System; but if I were you, I would definitely consider using this amazing solution and DRY principle of software dev; https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus